# Django ORM extremely slow

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

my Database had only 2 rows.
and when execute below query. taken time was about 2 seconds.

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
parks=Park.objects.filter(id='test')
end = datetime.datetime.now()
print('parks : '+str(parks))
print('duration : ' + str(end-start))
```

sql query on mysql command line was 0.1s.
django shell was also fine.

could you help me my case?

Comment: why are you using strings for your id (i presume your pk)? No wonder its "slow". You should try to make an [mcve].

Comment: install Django debug toolbar and you will get a better idea of what is actually going on.  https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: thanks for answer. I'll again try debug toolbar

Answer (score 0):

1) Install django debug toolbar https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

2) Why are you using a string for an id?

Comment: the id is "login id". not pk. and could use debug toolbar on rest framework for django? honestly don't know how. (already installed)